# How to distribute required *.dll files with your application?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sqlite

How to distribute required *.dll files with your application ?

I want to include System.Data.SQLite.DLL file

Comment: Distribute how? Are you creating a setup program? Are you using the Publish system? Click-once? Manual copying? Distribute where, to whom?

Comment: I am trying to create a set up program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an assembly to your setup project:

1. In the File System View of your Setup Project, click on Application Folder.
2. Right click in the right pane and choose Add>>Assembly.
3. Navigate to your System.Data.SQLite.dll and click OK.

System.Data.SQLite.dll should now be part of your project and install when you run it.